Use of archive.org PDFs of out-of-copyright books
The Internet archive (archive.org) has a large library of digitised old books which are available to view online and also as PDF downloads.  For the purpose of this question, let’s assume the books of interest are all out of copyright, though I’m aware that can be a complex question to answer.
The site’s terms of use start by saying ‘When accessing an archived page, you will be presented with the terms of use agreement‘.  I’m unclear whether ‘an archived page’ is supposed to include a digitised book, but you’re not presented with the terms of use when accessing a book (even in a private browsing window), and certainly don’t have to explicitly accept the terms.  Nevertheless, I dare say there’s an argument that you’re still bound by them.  They say that use is governed by Californian law.  If it’s relevant, I’m accessing site from England.
The terms of use say very little about what you can do with digitised books, other than that you must respect the original work’s copyright.  I do not know whether English law is relevant and whether similar provisions hold in other jurisdictions, but in England, a recent Court of Appeal case, THJ v Sheridan, has ruled that there is no copyright interest in images of documents or 2D works of art that are themselves out of copyright.  Obviously you are still subject to whatever terms you consented to in accessing the site, and they could say you mustn’t reproduce or distribute any images you download, though in this case they seem not to say anything like that.
Can I assume in this situation that I am free to use the PDFs however I want?  (What I want to do is thoroughly unobjectionable: I want to clean up the images a bit, fix some errors in the OCR, add PDF bookmarks, and make them available for free download on a personal site, acknowledging that they were originally from the Internet Archive, with a link back to the originals.)
